# Laravel 5.6 - Problems using Eloquent to return most recent date in datetime field of related table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have two tables: patients and appts (appointments). There is a one:many relationship patient:appt. My goal is to return a collection of patients, and from the relation the dates of the patient's last and next appointments.

### Problem / Issue

I'm getting inconsistent results. I've seeded the data so that each patient has appointments in the past and future, but when I use Eloquent to query (see 'Controller' below), I don't get a "lastappt".  If I modify the query to search by the patient's id, I do get the lastappt.

### The 'Patient' Model

```
class Patient extends Model
{
    ...
    public function appts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Appt');
    }
    public function lastappt()
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        return $this
            ->hasMany('App\Models\Appt')
            ->select(['id', 'patient_id', 'appt_date_time'])
            ->where('appt_date_time', '<', $now)
            ->orderBy('appt_date_time', 'desc')
            ->take(1);
    }
    public function nextappt()
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        return $this
            ->hasMany('App\Models\Appt')
            ->select(['id', 'patient_id', 'appt_date_time'])
            ->where('appt_date_time', '>', $now)
            ->orderBy('appt_date_time', 'asc')
            ->take(1);
    }
}
```

### The 'Appts' Migration

```
Schema::create('appts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('patient_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('hospital_id')->unsigned();
    ...
    $table->datetime('appt_date_time')->nullable();
    ...
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->index(['patient_id', 'hospital_id', 'appt_date_time']);
    $table->foreign('patient_id')
        ->references('id')->on('patients')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

### The Controller

```
$currPatientCollection = Patient::with('lastappt')
    ->with('nextappt')
    ->where('office_id', $user->office_id)
    ->where('current_patient', true)
    ->orderBy('last_name')
    ->orderBy('first_name')
    ->get();
```

This returns a nextappt only, even though the database has appts in the past.  The following query works (as I 'expected'), though, and returns the patient record with the lastappt and the nextappt.

```
$currPatientCollection = Patient::with('lastappt')
    ->with('nextappt')
    ->where('id', 1)
    ->where('current_patient', true)
    ->orderBy('last_name')
    ->orderBy('first_name')
    ->get();
```

Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
public function lastappt()
{
    $now = Carbon::now();
    return $this
        ->hasOne('App\Models\Appt')
        ->select(['id', 'patient_id', 'appt_date_time'])
        ->where('appt_date_time', '<', $now->toDateTimeString())
        ->orderBy('appt_date_time', 'desc')
        ->groupBy('patient_id');
}

public function nextappt()
{
    $now = Carbon::now();
    return $this
        ->hasOne('App\Models\Appt')
        ->select(['id', 'patient_id', 'appt_date_time'])
        ->where('appt_date_time', '>', $now->toDateTimeString())
        ->orderBy('appt_date_time', 'asc')
        ->groupBy('patient_id');
}
```

And now you can use:

```
$patient = Patient::find($someId);
echo $patient->lastappt->appt_date_time;
echo $patient->nextappt->appt_date_time;
```

Of course in above 3 lines you should assume that `lastappt` or `nextappt` might be null so you can use `optional` helper:

```
echo optional($patient->lastappt)->appt_date_time;
echo optional($patient->nextappt)->appt_date_time;
```

And of course when you have multiple patients you should eager load those relationships to avoid n+1 queries problem:

```
$patients = Patient::with('lastappt', 'nextappt')->whereIn('id', $someIds)->get();
```

Comment: For the person who downvoted - any reason why you downvoted this answer?